# R help is blank

Tags: r, macos

For some reason, the `R help` window became all blank.

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[R.app GUI 1.66 (6996) x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0]

> ?data.frame
```

[image: Screen shot]

I *think* this started after I upgraded to El Capitan but I am not sure (I have had this problem for a while). Removing `~/.Rprofile` doesn't help. Searching in the text field of the Help window doesn't work either.

`R` is normal otherwise. Help works fine with `R` running in Terminal. `R Data Editor` works.

I have Mac OS 10.11.1 (15B42), XQuartz 2.7.8, Java 8 Update 66. Thanks!

EDIT: forgot to mention that removing the entire R Framework and reinstalling `R` didn't help.

Comment: Lets get some more information by spying on R ([similar to using strace on Linux](http://jvns.ca/blog/2014/02/17/spying-on-ssh-with-strace/) with `dtruss` (OSX) with these steps:

1.  Fire up R.

2.  Open terminal.

3.  Find R process number (PID), `ps aux | grep -w R` (mine looks like below ...)

`statwonk        12164   0.0  1.0  3668764  86428   ??  S     7:25AM   0:09.17 /Applications/R.app`

4.  Then I take the PID 12164 and use it with `dtruss` to spy on R.

5.  `sudo dtruss -p 12164 -f write` (`-f write` filters output by the write system command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve the problem is by spying on R ([similar to using strace on Linux](http://jvns.ca/blog/2014/02/17/spying-on-ssh-with-strace/) with `dtruss` (OSX) with these steps:

1. Fire up R.
2. Open terminal.
3. Find R process number (PID), `ps aux | grep -w R` (mine looks like this ...)

   `statwonk        12164   0.0  1.0  3668764  86428   ??  S     7:25AM   0:09.17 /Applications/R.app ...`
4. Then I take the PID 12164 (number after username) and use it with `dtruss` to spy on R.
5. `sudo dtruss -p 12164 -t write` (`-t write` filters output by the write system command).
6. Go back to `R` and submit the command `?data.frame`.
7. The help page appears for me and `dtruss` spies,

   ```
   SYSCALL(args) = return
   write(0xE, "GET /library/base/html/data.frame.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1:23487\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-us\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macint", 0x148)            = 328 0
   ```
8. By using `dtruss` you can see what might be causing R to not show the help page! For example it might be helpful to redirect the output to a file like this,

   ```
       touch dtruss_out
       sudo dtruss -p 12164 2> dtruss_out
   ```

Comment: Thanks. There were no `write()` calls. The only thing close was `pwrite(0xC, "bplist00\245\001\032\"-7\334\002\003\004\005\006\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\016\017\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\030\031^NSWindowNumber]NSWindowFrameWNSTitle_\020\036NSWindowMiniaturizeButtonFrameVNSUIID_\020\027NSWindowZoomButtonFrameZNSWindowID\\NSDragRegion]NSWindowLevel_\020\023NSWindowWorkspaceID_\020\030NSWindowCloseButtonFrameYNSDataKey\021\030z_\020\035728 77 919 ", 0x638, 0x0)   = 1592 0`

Comment: @ceilingcat hmm, do you see anything related to `data.frame` like my example?

Comment: No. A bunch of lines like `SYSCALL(args)    = return
select(0x10, 0x10DF2E580, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7FFF521721F8)   = 0 0
open_nocancel(".\0", 0x0, 0x1)   = 17 0
fstat64(0x11, 0x7FFF52171BE0, 0x1)   = 0 0`

Comment: @ceilingcat when I startup R I see `starting httpd help server ... done.` See this thread, maybe this is a helpful clue? https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-February/226877.html

Comment: Your link helped me found the problem... it does have something to do with the network/proxy... I am usually VPN-ed in. And R help would not start in this environment. But if I disconnect VPN (and directly connecting to the internet) then R help works. Now even if I reconnect to my VPN, R help would continue to work. I guess I just have to remember to disconnect from VPN once at the beginning of each run. This is not a huge problem: since I don't need help if I call R from a script, and if I am running R interactively it's easy to do the work-around. Still seems like a bug though.

Comment: Glad the link helped, it seems pretty strange that it'll continue to work when you re-enable the VPN. It might be a bug, it seems like the httpd server isn't being started.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with the latest R (v3.5.1) for Mac. Anytime I tried to call a help file by typing

`help(dataset)`

in R Console, the pop up help window was blank. And following the process listening/spying method above did not help as there were no additional calls showing up other than:

`SYSCALL(args) = return`

This was frustrating as I am trying to learn R and learning a bit about the dataset before diving in is really helpful!

So I discovered that you can type:

`??dataset`

and the related help file in your browser window instead of through R's frame. I still don't know what is blocking R from access the help files, but this workaround saved me.